# Getting undefined result when trying to loop and filtering array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently working with objects and arrays in nodejs in conjuction with filters. I am currenlty facing difficulty in figuring out how to properly traverse an object and filter for the desired results. Instead I am getting `undefined`. I have an object `users` and I am wanting to filter for each user configuration that has `active === true` and then ultimately display every users configuration with that filter in the final result. What is the right/best way to approach this? Should I use `map`?

Current Result:

```
undefined
```

Desired Result:

```
[
    {
        email: 'test1@email.com',
        active: true
    },
    {
        email: 'test3@email.com',
        active: true
    },
    {
        email: 'test4@email.com',
        active: true
    }
]
```

Code:

```
const users = [
    {
      name: 'User1',
      configuration: [ 
          {
            email: 'test1@email.com',
            active: true
          },
          {
            email: 'test2@email.com',
            active: false
          }
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'User2',
      configuration: [ 
          {
            email: 'test3@email.com',
            active: true
          },
          {
            email: 'test4@email.com',
            active: true
          }
      ],
    },
];

const result = users.forEach(user => user.configuration.filter( x => {

    let {
        active
    } = x;

    return active === true;
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `flatMap` for this. `forEach` always returns `undefined`. usually if you want to return some array use `map` but since `filter` also returns an array you need to flat it to get your desired result hence `flatMap`

```js
const users = [{name: 'User1',configuration: [ {email: 'test1@email.com',active: true},{email: 'test2@email.com',active: false}],},{name: 'User2',configuration: [ {email: 'test3@email.com',active: true},{email: 'test4@email.com',active: true}],},];

const result = users.flatMap(user => user.configuration.filter( x => x.active===true));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use two `forEach` like so:

```js
const users = [
  {
    name: "User1",
    configuration: [
      {
        email: "test1@email.com",
        active: true
      },
      {
        email: "test2@email.com",
        active: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "User2",
    configuration: [
      {
        email: "test3@email.com",
        active: true
      },
      {
        email: "test4@email.com",
        active: true
      }
    ]
  }
];
let result =[];
users.forEach((user) =>
  user.configuration.forEach((x) => {
  if (x.active) {
    result.push(x)
  }
})
);

console.log(result);
```